# неправильно сохраняется иконка в unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я добавляю в настройках игры в icon иконку игры (512х512), а на некоторых телефонах отображается вот так криво. хотя, к примеру другие игры, сделанные на юнити, хорошо всё с иконкой. к примеру, вот стандофф 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Android? iOS? О каких телефонах речь?

Comment: android конечно

Comment: Нужна круглая еще.

Comment: типа в добавок к квадратной еще и круглую? и что тогда сделать?